# Error "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'File' of 'value'"

Tags: firebase, flutter, file, flutter-getx

This is my **page one** where I am using **getX** to pass the file path as **String** to next page. for uploading to Firebase storage and then to get download url to pass it to firebase cloud firestore but its showing the above error

```
imagePath = cropped.path;

print(imagePath);
pollImageController.setImage(imagePath);
```

This is how I am getting the String in next page (I can print the path correctly but this isn't type File)

```
String imagepath = pollImageController.imageDisplay.value;
```

**this is the page code for upload image with some other database part**

```
.
.

  static String pollPostId = Uuid().v4();
  String finalimagePath = '$imagepath/imag_$pollPostId';
.
.
  handleSubmit() async {
    setState(() {
      isUploading = true;
    });

    String mediaUrl = await uploadImage(finalimagePath);

    cratePollPostInFireStore(
      mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
      caption: captionpass,
      category: captionpass,
    );
    //ashrith clear the state here
    //example to clear controller:
    //categoryController.clear();
    setState(() {
      isUploading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<String> uploadImage(imageFile) async {
    firebase_storage.UploadTask uploadTask =
        storageRef.child("post_$pollPostId.jpg").putFile(imageFile);
    firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot storageSnap = await uploadTask;
    String downloadurl = await storageSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadurl;
  }

  cratePollPostInFireStore({String mediaUrl, String caption, String category}) {
    pollPostRef.doc(_uid).collection("usersPollPosts").doc(pollPostId).set({
      "pollPostid": pollPostId,
      "ownerId": _uid,
      "username": _username,
      "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
      "caption": caption,
      "category": category,
      "timespanmp": timestamp,
      "polls": {},
    });
  }
}
```

**As per I understood we could not pass string to File type ,that's why I am getting this error .**

So does anyone knows the solution .It helps me a lot .I am fully stuck right now .

thank you :)

Comment: As I see it, `.putFile()` takes a File, not a String path. Try changing `Future<String> uploadImage(imageFile) {` to `Future<String> uploadImage(final File imageFile) {` to see compile-time exceptions, otherwise your IDE cant tell since your `imageFile` is `dynamic` in the scope.

Comment: Also, this is a matter of taste, but consider always writing argument type in named functions and using `final`, you might gain in performance and see exceptions in compile-time rather than runtime

Comment: Now i am geting the error here 
"String mediaUrl = await uploadImage(finalimagePath);"

Error "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type "

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: You are still providing a String as a parameter, perhaps this will do: 
`String mediaUrl = await uploadImage(File(finalimagePath))`

Comment: **Now I am getting the following error**
'_AssertionError ('package:firebase_storage/src/reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 133 pos 12: 'file.absolute.existsSync()': is not true.)'